# Singular measures on a metric space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I have been working on this problem (By Daniel Stroock): Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Recall that two measures $\mu, \nu$ on $E$ are *singular* (written $\mu \bot \nu$) if there is a set $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $\mu(B) = \nu(E \backslash B) = 0$. I would like to show that:

> $\mu \bot \nu$ if and only if for every $\delta > 0$, there is an open set $G$ so that $\nu(G) < \delta$ and $\mu(E \backslash G) = 0$

I was able to get the forwards direction after some thought, but am quite stuck on the reverse direction. Right now, I am trying:

For every positive integer $n$, by hypothesis, there is an open set $G$ so that $\nu(G_n) < 1/n$ and $\mu(G_n^C) = 0$. Put $G = \underset{n \geq 1}{\bigcap} G_n \in \mathcal{B}$.

Then I try to show that $G$ is the separating set I am looking for. Am I looking in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You may assume, without loss of generality,  that the sequence $G_n$ decreases. Indeed,

Repalcating $G_n$ by $G'_n=\bigcap^n_{k=1}G_k$ if necessary, you get that
$$\nu(G'_n)\leq\nu(G_n)<\frac1n$$
and
$$\mu(E\setminus G'_n)\leq\mu(\bigcup^n_{k=1}E\setminus G_k)\leq\sum^n_{k=1}\mu(E\setminus G_k)=0$$

The rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\lim \inf G_n$. ($G$ is the set of points that belong to $G_n$ for infinitely many $n$). Then $\nu (G)=0$ since, by Fatou's Lemma $\mu (g) \leq \lim \inf \nu(G_n)=0$. Also $\mu(E\setminus G) \leq \mu (\cup_n E\setminus G_n)\leq \sum \mu(E\setminus G_n)=0$.

[I am applying Fatou's Lemma to $f_n=\chi_{G_n}$].